# "Accept the cookies" popup with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to just click on the accept button of the website but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.justwatch.com/fr/films")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Accepter tout"]').click()
```

error message: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@title="Accepter tout"]"}`

I've tried using other methods than the title to find the button but nothing worked.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTML you will see that the button is contained inside `#shadow-root (open)`.

[image]

You can get rid off that by using this code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

shadow_parent = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#usercentrics-root')
outer = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_parent)
inner = outer.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')
inner.click()
```